# Too many running php processes. Will exit(0) make a difference?

Tags: php

I did a website for one of my clients a long time ago, and the website really grew big. The code was pretty amateur. Now years down the road his website is going down due to too many running php processes. I would like to know what could be the reason for this. The things I think I was doing wrong were:

1. not closing db connections.
2. not destroying php objects.

   Could these be the reasons?

Also is it good to `exit(0)` a php script at the end? Will it help?

Comment: Let me guess: `apache` at frontend? If yes, the it's the problem since httpd will fork new thread on each connection. Use something like `nginx` for frontend and let apache handle backend. That could be a first step to improve your application

Comment: Please make sure you _don't_ use persistent mysql connections (using eg. `mysql_pconnect()` function). That could really go wrong when connections are not explicitly closed (normal connections are closed by php itself)

Answer (score 1):

Too many running PHP or httpd processes?
If httpd, it is due to apache configuration.
Apache can keep processes running ready to be used when incoming request will need to be processed.

I don't think this is caused either by DB connections or not destroying PHP objects:
- PHP variables are automatically destroyed when they are not needed
- DB connections should be automatically closed when script ends.

Comment: How can I better configure apache?

Comment: I am pretty sure its PHP process as was told by hosting company

Comment: It is shared server? How is PHP installed? As fast-cgi? Or apache module?

Comment: Its a dedicated server. Let me get to you on that.